# i want get option selected with js?

Tags: javascript

i want get option selected with js but me code return undifine ?
where is error

```js
const aaa = document.querySelector("#test")

const rng = aaa.addEventListener("change",(e)=>{
  return e.target.selectedOptions[e.target.selectedIndex].text
})
console.log(rng)
```

```html
<select id="test">
      <option value="a">a</option>
      <option value="b">b</option>
      <option value="c">c</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you are assigning the addEventListener to your const `rng`, and it's returning `undefined` that's why you get undefined, the callback function will not return to this context

Second, `selectedOptions` here, for a single select input, will be only one item represented as an object where you can get the element itself by the key `0`, you shouldn't try to access it by the real index in the options list

Finally, get the innerText of this element

ex:

```js
const selectElement = document.querySelector("#test")

selectElement.addEventListener("change",(e)=>{
  console.log(e.target.selectedOptions[0].innerText)
})
```

```html
<select id="test">
      <option value="a">a</option>
      <option value="b">b</option>
      <option value="c">c</option>
</select>
```

Or you can get the element using `querySelector`:

```js
const selectElement = document.querySelector("#test")

selectElement.addEventListener("change",(e)=>{
  console.log(selectElement.querySelector("option:checked").innerText)
})
```

```html
<select id="test">
      <option value="a">a</option>
      <option value="b">b</option>
      <option value="c">c</option>
</select>
```